# Can blender be used to remap textures to a different format?

Tags: texturing

I am a Engineering Student who is creating a simulation of a Porsche for his final year dissertation. I have a question about blender and is it possible for the software to remap textures into a different format?

I have the texture for the car in the format below:
[image]

and would like it to be in this format:

[image]

The original file is from assetto corsa and it needs to be converted to work with a Cruden Driving simulator (software is called panthera)

Is this possible and if so how do you do it? Or is using photoshop and moving the first image around the best way?

I have never used blender so sorry if i am missing any information.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, Henry. Unfortunately, you have to edit it externally with an Image Editor, peace by peace.

Comment: Okay, thank you!